# What exactly is Ousama Game in this titular series? How does it work?

Tags: ousama-game

I read the manga recently because I was watching the anime and I am a little confused about the game and the virus.

So can anyone please explain the Ousama Game? Not the manga but *the game in the manga*.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article on [Konpa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konpa) (which are basically alcohol-fueled "get to know each other" events) describes it. Basically, the rules are:

1. Everyone gets a piece of paper which either has a number on it, or identifies them as the king.
2. The King reveals themselves.
3. The King issues a decree/dare, including some of the numbers (for example "Number 2 has to kiss number 3's index finger").
4. The people whose numbers match the decree reveal themselves and do the dare.

It's a bit like a semi-anonymous version of Truth or Dare.